# How to mute the audio of a application in ubuntu?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, terminal

i'm working on a project which produces sound alerts whenever a condition is met. But the problem is if the video player is running the alert sound get mixed with the sound of the video. Is there any way to mute the audio of the running application only using terminal so that the warning can be heard.
My operating system is **Ubuntu.**

Comment: What programming language/framework are you wanting to do this in?

Comment: basic shell scripts

Comment: Which shell do you use?

Comment: Bash shell scripting

Comment: Ubuntu should be using pulseaudio I believe. So some combination of pactl / pacmd / pasuspender is probably what you want. See "man -k pulse".

Comment: i'm not getting exact way to do it

Comment: Got it working...